# Is there any shortcut/easy way to switch this system proxy settings?

Tags: macos, proxy

Sometimes I need to send my traffic to a proxy, sometimes I don't.

Currently, I have to go to the settings every time to click it.

Is there any simple way for me to switch this? For instance, use a shell command to do this.

[image: system proxy]

Comment: `sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy "USB 10/100/1000 LAN" 127.0.0.1 8888` / 
`sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate "USB 10/100/1000 LAN" off` / `sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate "USB 10/100/1000 LAN" on` works great.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done with `networksetup`.

Get all services:

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

Then with the proper service (e.g Ethernet or the name of your USB 10/100/1000 LAN adapter) enter

```
sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy <networkservice> <domain> <port number> <authenticated> <username> <password>
```

or

```
sudo networksetup -setwebproxy <networkservice> <domain> <port number> <authenticated> <username> <password>
```

to configure it (which isn't necessary in your case, because you already entered all necessary values).

e.g.

```
sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy Ethernet 127.0.0.1 18080
sudo networksetup -setwebproxy Ethernet 127.0.0.1 18080
```

**To simply toggle it on or off use:**

```
sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate networkservice on | off
sudo networksetup -setwebproxystate networkservice on | off
```

e.g.

```
sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate Ethernet off
sudo networksetup -setwebproxystate Ethernet off
```

`man networksetup` will reveal other proxy options (gopher, ftp, etc.)

Answer (score 11):

Use "Locations" under Network Preferences.

[image]

Set up a location that has the proxy and then a location that doesn't.  When you want to use the proxy, pick that location and your settings will change.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page](https://yourmacguy.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/networksetup-command/) at YourMacGuy about the Terminal command `networksetup`. Although the page dates from 2008, the command exists and works in macOS Sierra. Perhaps one of the proxy-related commands will work for you. You can always create multiple Locations in System Preferences > Network that can enable or disable the proxy. You will still need to open System Preferences, though.

Answer (score 0):

I do it by defining shortcuts in [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/). Now I can toggle the system proxy with just shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

Source code available on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/BigSully/0e59ab97f148bc167ea19dbd42ebef4b).

Here is the setup steps:

1. Set the IP and port of http and https proxy manually for the first time, which can be accomplished in command line though.

```
networksetup -setwebproxy "Wi-fi" 127.0.0.1 8080
networksetup -setsecurewebproxy "Wi-fi" 127.0.0.1 8080
```

2. Add the following shell function to your `~/.profile`

```
toggleProxy() {
    e=$(networksetup -getwebproxy wi-fi | grep "No")

    ns=wi-fi
    status=''
    if [ -n "$e" ]; then
      status=on
    else
      status=off
    fi

    echo -n "Turning $status proxy"
    networksetup -setstreamingproxystate $ns $status
    networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate $ns $status
    networksetup -setwebproxystate $ns $status
    networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate  $ns $status
}
```

3. Add the following to your `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua`

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl"}, "P", function()
  local output = hs.execute("toggleProxy", true)
  hs.alert.show(output)
end)
```